# Maximum Profit Calculator Java

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop

If a cinema sells tickets for $5 and averages 100 tickets sold per show, the cost per person is $2. For each reduction in price of $0.25, the number of tickets sold increases by 30 and the cost per person increases by $0.10. Print a table showing the price (ranging from $5 to $3,) the number of tickets sold, cost per person, gross revenue, total cost, net profit. Indicate the maximum profit.

I'm having trouble approaching this question and I am looking for help in being guided in the right direction. I'm not very good at coding, and am doing this for practice. I have tried using my knowledge using arrays but to no avail. Appreciate the help.

```
/* If a cinema sells tickets for $5 and averages 100 tickets sold per show,
   the cost per person is $2.
   For each reduction in price of $0.25,
   the number of tickets sold increases by 30 and the cost per person increases by $0.10.
   Print a table showing the price (ranging from $5 to $3,) the number of tickets sold,
   cost per person, gross revenue, total cost, net profit. Indicate the maximum profit.
 */
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class MaxProfitCalc {
public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (double ticketCost = 5.0; ticketCost >= 3.0; ticketCost-=0.25 ) {
                System.out.printf("Ticket cost is: " + "%.2f\n", ticketCost);
        }
        for (double costPerPerson = 2.0; costPerPerson <= 2.80; costPerPerson+=0.10 ) {
                System.out.printf("Cost per person is: " + "%.2f\n", costPerPerson);
        }
        for (int ticketSold = 100; ticketSold <= 340; ticketSold+=30 ) {
                System.out.println("Amount of tickets sold: " + ticketSold);
        }
}
}
```

***EDIT*** I have figured out how to print the numbers, now it is a matter of calculating the numbers. Is there any way to access the highest number in order to figure out the maximum profit, gross revenue, and total cost? Would I have to create an array or can is there a way to grab the numbers from the for loops themselves?

Comment: Do something, then come back for direction. My daughter learned to walk by trying to walk.

Comment: I believe this would be better in [programmer.se] if your seek for advice about how to analyse this problem. @Bathsheba, best advice, but I hope you will help her when she will learn to ride a bike ;)

Comment: Would it be logical to create an array and a while loop?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would approach the problem. For some basic direction:

1. Find out how to solve the math for the problem on paper.
2. Programmatically write the math within a method (or break it up into several methods) within Java.
3. Find out how to print the information into a the console with java ( HINT: check out System.out.println(""); for starters). Maybe look at how to Format strings as well.

Don't let the negative responses on Stack Overflow get you down. Programming is an intimidating thing to start, but the best programmers are those who remain persistent. Good luck!

Comment: Would it be logical to create an array and a while loop? As in use the while loop to increase the amount of tickets sold while price reduces up to 3 dollars?

Comment: As with most programming problems, there are multiple implementations you could use to solve it. I do not necessarily disagree that a while loop or array could be used to solve this problem, but personally think those kinds of questions are a bit premature at this point. One thing at a time! 

Solve the math on paper, get the program to perform the math, and then optimize it. Show us your work as you go.